# Deserialize int array always nulll

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

When I deserialize JSON string in to object int array property always set null. But other properties working find. here is the sample JSON

```
{
   "userId":"1a163282-85ac-4ffb-94c6-20afb9473449",
   "clientCode":"Explicabo",
   "companies":[
      {
         "id":"982df206-efe2-40dc-a86c-e949d8b7f8f3",
         "clientId":"ea146f0d-e1b5-43e8-a3f2-7452b27a8e6a",
         "code":"CMP000008",
         "databaseInfo":{
            "userId":"lahujo",
            "password":"Aspernatur perspicia",
            "server":"Est assumenda autem ",
            "modules":[
               3,
               2
            ],
            "subModules":[
               2
            ],
            "database":"C_Explicabo_KatelynDean"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":"c3894d01-eba7-45b2-9b47-0a7ed8752c4b",
         "clientId":"ea146f0d-e1b5-43e8-a3f2-7452b27a8e6a",
         "code":"CMP000007",
         "databaseInfo":{
            "userId":"lahujo",
            "password":"Aspernatur perspicia",
            "server":"Est assumenda autem ",
            "modules":[
               3,
               2
            ],
            "subModules":[
               2
            ],
            "database":"C_Explicabo_LunaandDunnTraders"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":"e16d1d33-c050-4e58-9dce-b09616425fff",
         "clientId":"ea146f0d-e1b5-43e8-a3f2-7452b27a8e6a",
         "code":"CMP000009",
         "databaseInfo":{
            "userId":"lahujo",
            "password":"Aspernatur perspicia",
            "server":"Est assumenda autem ",
            "modules":[
               3,
               2
            ],
            "subModules":[
               2
            ],
            "database":"C_Explicabo_PatrickReilly"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

When I deserialize, the object return like below

```
{
  "userId": "1a163282-85ac-4ffb-94c6-20afb9473449",
  "clientCode": "Explicabo",
  "companies": [
    {
      "id": "982df206-efe2-40dc-a86c-e949d8b7f8f3",
      "clientId": "ea146f0d-e1b5-43e8-a3f2-7452b27a8e6a",
      "code": "CMP000008",
      "payRollYear": 0,
      "modules": [],
      "subModules": [],
      "databaseInfo": {
        "userId": "lahujo",
        "password": "Aspernatur perspicia",
        "server": "Est assumenda autem ",
        "database": "C_Explicabo_KatelynDean"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "c3894d01-eba7-45b2-9b47-0a7ed8752c4b",
      "clientId": "ea146f0d-e1b5-43e8-a3f2-7452b27a8e6a",
      "code": "CMP000007",
      "payRollYear": 0,
      "modules": [],
      "subModules": [],
      "databaseInfo": {
        "userId": "lahujo",
        "password": "Aspernatur perspicia",
        "server": "Est assumenda autem ",
        "database": "C_Explicabo_LunaandDunnTraders"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "e16d1d33-c050-4e58-9dce-b09616425fff",
      "clientId": "ea146f0d-e1b5-43e8-a3f2-7452b27a8e6a",
      "code": "CMP000009",
      "payRollYear": 0,
      "modules": [],
      "subModules": [],
      "databaseInfo": {
        "userId": "lahujo",
        "password": "Aspernatur perspicia",
        "server": "Est assumenda autem ",
        "database": "C_Explicabo_PatrickReilly"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using Newton JSON Serializer to deserialize the object `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json)`

Company Model

```
public class CompanyInfoModel
{
    public CompanyInfoModel()
    {
        Modules = new List<int>();
        SubModules = new List<int>();
    }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int PayRollYear { get; set; }
    public List<int> Modules { get; set; }
    public List<int> SubModules { get; set; }
    public DbServerModel DatabaseInfo { get; set; }
}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your input JSON your `modules` and `subModules` properties are members of `databaseInfo` and so should not be in your `CompanyInfoModel` class, they should be in your `DbServerModel` class.

```
{
         "id":"982df206-efe2-40dc-a86c-e949d8b7f8f3",
         "clientId":"ea146f0d-e1b5-43e8-a3f2-7452b27a8e6a",
         "code":"CMP000008",
         "databaseInfo":{
            "userId":"lahujo",
            "password":"Aspernatur perspicia",
            "server":"Est assumenda autem ",
            "modules":[                       // <-- this is NOT a member of CompanyInfo. It's in "databaseInfo".
               3,
               2
            ],
            "subModules":[                    // <-- Ditto.
               2
            ],
            "database":"C_Explicabo_KatelynDean"
         }
      }
```

Comment: ohh damn .. thank you very much for pointing out. what a shame :(